# Dependencies between tests in scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I want to test a complex workflow, both by unit-testing its components, and running an integration test for the whole thing, without running sub-components twice unnecessarily.

For example, routine `c` processes the results of `a` and `b`. I would like to have the following test suites:

- Unit test 1: Running `a` and validating the results
- Unit test 2: Running `b` and validating the results
- Nightly integration test: Running `a` and `b`, validating their results, then running `c` and validating its results, *without re-running `a` and `b`*, but re-using the outputs

Running each component takes some time, so the obvious solution of "just run everything every time" is not practical.

The code is in Scala, but I don't care which test framework to use - scalatest, specs2, even TestNG, all are fine, though I would prefer a Scala-ish solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Reusing the ouputs" means your unit tests would have produced some artifact, which the nightly integration test will consume. This is probably a bad practice that will end up hurting you more often than not. Unless those tests truly take a large amount of time, i'd repeat them, or find better ways to verify their output (DRYer tests, don't test the same everywhere)

Comment: These are tests for data analysis algorithms. I prepared mock data sets to minimize the tests run time, but it is still non-negligible, especially for the complete flow. From my experience, if the tests would be too slow, developers would be reluctant to run and maintain them, hence the problem.

Comment: if the test ouput is constant, the you can start the integration test using a materialized result like a json file. if the output is different, then your unit tests really are part of your integration test, and you want to try to distance them a bit more.